# JQuery Validation plugin with Sijax

Tags: jquery, python, jquery-validate, sijax

I'm trying to check wether usernames are valid with the JQuery Validation plugin with Sijax. This means I use Sijax (Ajax, Python) to verify on the server if the user already exists or not. I added this method to the Validation plugin:

```
$.validator.addMethod("availableName", function(value, element) {
        var check = true;
        var username = $("#username").val();
        Sijax.request('checkuser', [username]); 
        if (usercheck) {
            check = false;
            usercheck = false;
        } 
        return check },
        "That username is no longer available");
```

The checkuser method on the server checks the availability of the username and changes the value of the usercheck variable. I checked with firebug and the method usercheck (wich calls another javascript method to change the usercheck) does send the right response but maybe it skips the other lines?

The problem I have now is that **the validation of the username field only happens when I focus and blur it twice.** Every other field works just fine. 
This means for example if the username "Jon" already exist this happens:

- I enter Jon and blur the field -> nothing happens
- Re-focus and blur
  the field -> "This username already exists"

Even if I change the username that doesn't exists (e.g. to Jon1234) after the re-focus it still says "This username already exists". So I think this means the field is behind one step but I don't know why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so `Sijax.request()` returns as soon as the request is sent, it doesn't wait for the response. So the `usercheck` variable won't have been updated yet.  Instead of Sijax, I suggest you use jquery-validate's built-in `remote` validation method.

Comment: I'm using the Flask framework with jinja templates, so for me this would be something like this:
remote: {{ url_for('checkuser/username') }} with the checkuser method a method in flask returning the right answer in json?

Comment: or maybe it would be possible to set the async variable of jQuery.ajax to false before executing the sijax request?

Comment: I'm not failiar with Flask, but that code looks like it's probably right. Synchronous AJAX is not generally recommended, I'm not sure if it would really solve the problem.